# Web API in Android

Tags: android

I have been given a task to make a data feed app and I have been provided a sample JSON data. This is the exact problem statement.

Problem Statement

Develop an android app to display the attached data as a feed.
Requirements

1). Use of Web API to fetch data (PFA, sample data).
2). Use Recycler view to list the item.

This is the JSON FILE which they have given me

```
[  
   {  
      "type":"CONTENT",
      "title":"",
      "data":{  
         "name":"Jhon",
         "profile_img_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NBa3Y9qqiS4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABtA/z18p98Ny--Q/s36-p-k-rw-no/photo.jpg",
         "question":"What are the next numbers in this series: 2.5, 4, 7, 10,16,19??",
         "posted_on":"1481263449"
      }
   },
   {  
      "type":"HORIZONTAL_IMAGE_LIST",
      "title":"Suggested for you",
      "data":[  
         {  
            "card_img_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-vZkSLb7rJlA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACQ/9XEOfxXIMUo/w320-h180-p-rw/photo.jpg",
            "title":"Recruitment Essentials",
            "followers":"10000"
         },
         {  
            "card_img_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-vZkSLb7rJlA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACQ/9XEOfxXIMUo/w320-h180-p-rw/photo.jpg",
            "title":"Speed Maths",
            "followers":"10000"
         },
         {  
            "card_img_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-vZkSLb7rJlA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACQ/9XEOfxXIMUo/w320-h180-p-rw/photo.jpg",
            "title":"Test",
            "followers":"12000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "type":"CONTENT",
      "title":"",
      "data":{  
         "name":"Sandeep",
         "profile_img_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kPeVZhvqjNE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADs/60B5PdpPF64/s36-p-k-rw-no/photo.jpg",
         "question":"What are the next numbers in this series: 2.5, 4, 7, 10,16,19??",
         "posted_on":"1481233449"
      }
   },
   {  
      "type":"IMAGE",
      "title":"",
      "data":{           
         "img_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kPeVZhvqjNE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADs/60B5PdpPF64/s36-p-k-rw-no/photo.jpg"         
      }
   }
]
```

Basically I am not understanding the meaning of first requirement line can anyone explain it

Comment: Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: What do you mean by the "first line"? Do you mean the opening `[` of the JSON?

Comment: First requirement line

Answer (score 0):

You may need some data to display in your mobile application which will come from server part, the server will provide data to you in JSON format when you sent a request to the server. In android, there are tons of tools available to manage request and response from the server but retrofit is the most used library. to get started with retrofit refer this link [Getting start with retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/tag/retrofit)

Comment: According to you I will have to make my own server then only I will be able to use retrofit after that only because till now I have only JSON response.